# Chromecast App ID Not Working

Tags: android, google-cast, app-id

This is a follow-up to this question: [What do I do if my Chromecast AppID isn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010224/what-do-i-do-if-my-chromecast-appid-isnt-working)

I have to APP IDs, a local one, and a remote one. Using the code in the aforementioned question, whenever I set the app id to the remote one, my Chromecast DOES show up. The moment I change it to the local one, however, it does not.

My device is whitelisted, it sends its serial number during updates, naturally, and it is only the local IP which is not working. The local app id links to the following URL:

```
http://192.168.2.125/HelloCast/receiver.php
```

That is verbatim the link I received from Google (even though there's little you can do with it outside my home network). I know that it does not have anything to do with the contents of the URL, for the target of the remote app id does not even exist, and yet the Chromecast does accept it as a valid ID.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "this is verbatim the link I received from Google". Google doesn't assign you any receiver url, you decide what it is. Regardless, since for your remote app ID you can see the cast button, it means your device is whitelisted. Please double check the app ID for the local one to make sure you are entering it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I sent Google the two links, and that is the app id for the local link. I copied the app id directly from Google's email.

Comment: Do we need a specific Id for local app even when only the sender is on localhost and the receiver is at the given url ?